# Sentences about relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $R,S$ relations.

Then, I have to prove the following sentences:

1. $dom(R \circ S) \subset domS$
2. $rng(R \circ S) \subset rngR$
3. $(R \circ S)^{-1}=S^{-1} \circ R^{-1}$
4. If $A=fld(R)$, then $I_A \circ R=R$ and $R \circ I_A=R$

That's what I have tried:

1. Let $x \in dom(R \circ S)$. Then $\exists y $, such that: $<x,y> \in R \circ S$. This means that $\exists z$, such that $<x,z> \in S$ and $<z,y> \in R \rightarrow x \in domS$

Therefore, $dom(R \circ S) \subset domS$

1. Let $y \in rng(R \circ S)$. Then, $\exists x$, such that: $<x,y> \in R \circ S$.This means that $\exists z$, such that $<x,z> \in S$ and $<z,y> \in R \rightarrow y \in rng R$

Therefore, $rng(R \circ S) \subset rng R$.

Am I right? How could I prove the sentences 3,4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you handle 1) and 2) is correct.

3. equivalent are the following statements:

   - $\left\langle z,x\right\rangle \in\left(R\circ S\right)^{-1}$
   - $\left\langle x,z\right\rangle \in R\circ S$
   - $\exists y\left\langle x,y\right\rangle \in S\wedge\left\langle y,z\right\rangle \in R$
   - $\exists y\left\langle y,x\right\rangle \in S^{-1}\wedge\left\langle z,y\right\rangle \in R^{-1}$
   - $\left\langle z,x\right\rangle \in S^{-1}\circ R^{-1}$
4. equivalent are the following statements:

   - $\left\langle x,z\right\rangle \in I_{A}\circ R$
   - $\exists y\left\langle x,y\right\rangle \in R\wedge\left\langle y,z\right\rangle \in I_{A}$
   - $\exists y\left\langle x,y\right\rangle \in R\wedge y=z$
   - $\left\langle x,z\right\rangle \in R$

and also the following:

- $\left\langle x,z\right\rangle \in R\circ I_{A}$
- $\exists y\left\langle x,y\right\rangle \in I_{A}\wedge\left\langle y,z\right\rangle \in R$
- $\exists y\; x=y\wedge\left\langle y,z\right\rangle \in R$
- $\left\langle x,z\right\rangle \in R$

Comment: drhab Nice!!! I got it.. Thank you very much!!! :-)

Comment: You are very welcome.